# Pandas Groupby Count Partial Strings

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am wanting to try to get a count of how many rows within a column contain a partial string based on an imported dataframe. In the sample data below, I want to groupby Trans_type and then get a count of how many rows contain a value.

[image: Table of Sample Data]

So I would expect to see:

[image: Grouped_Counts]

First, is this possible generically without passing a link to get each types expected brand? If not, how could I pass say Car a list of .str.contains['Audi','BMW'].

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `df['Brand'] = df['Brand'].str[:-1]`, then `df.groupby(['Trans_Type, 'Brand'])['Brand'].size()`

Comment: @Erfan I appreciate your quick response. Thank you for helping my tired brain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
df.groupby(df["Trans_type"], df["Brand"].str.extract("([a-zA-Z])+", expand=False)).count()
```